# How to run Kafka server for development purpose?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I need to run kafka server for development purposes in simplest way as posible. Just one static topic on local server, no auth needed (or SASL\Plaintext, if it simple). All i need to do is send and receive messages in JSON-like format. How can i do it?

Why kafka? Because my project will be part of more bigger project and i need to use external libs to work with kafka.

---

I found out [this](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker) and run it though command:

```sh
docker-compose up -d
```

This was my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

But with my golang and python clients i cannot send or receive messages to `localhost:9092`: broker time out. Maybe i need to change anything else?

Comment: Can you share the output of `docker ps` and `docker logs <<container_id>>`

Comment: Logs are too long to post it here. Share via github gist: [clickMe](https://gist.github.com/catexis/d4e3bb331cd2ad36483fd6ffb190c2de)

Answer (score 2):

`KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` needs to be set to the host where your clients can go to communicate with the broker.  This should be the IP of your docker host, but it is set to `kafka` instead, which is not resolvable by your clients.

As per [instructions posted with the docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/) in "Pre-Requisites":

> modify the `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` in docker-compose.yml to match
> your docker host IP (Note: Do not use localhost or 127.0.0.1 as the
> host ip if you want to run multiple brokers.)

Here is what is happening:

- You are using `localhost:9092` as your "bootstrap broker" address in your clients, so that is where your clients are going to make their initial connection
- Once connected, your client is given whatever is in `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` as the hostname it should use from then on to contact the broker.  In your case, this is `kafka` (incorrect).
- Your client then disconnects and tries to connect to `kafka`.  Since there is not a route to a host named `kafka` from your client, your client cannot proceed.

Try setting `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` to be the IP of your docker host and see if you have better luck.  (Also, you probably also should use that same host IP as the bootstrap broker you use in your clients, instead of `localhost`.)

Comment: Ok. [This](https://gist.github.com/catexis/45a97ae28a9f02b4cd22adc007b9d97f) my new yaml file. I can ping address `172.20.128.2` from host. [This](https://gist.github.com/catexis/5f020dc1b65a0651651563cd6f31639f) my client in golang (producer + consumer). I still can't send or receive messages.

Comment: Hostname property is deprecated, though

Answer (score 1):

The `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` variable can be set to `localhost:29092`. This makes Kafka accessible from outside the container by advertising its location on the Docker host.

Refer [this](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/config-reference.html) for more info.

Comment: In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63621061/how-to-run-kafka-server-for-development-purpose#comment112523766_63622567) situation i still can't send and receive messages.